# Circle is wobbling by y axis rotation

Tags: android, matrix, camera, android-canvas

I'm currently learning some drawing techniques in Android by overwriting the onDraw method of my custom view. 
I just recently wanted to draw a circle and flip the circle on its y axis. Just like a coin flip. But somehow, it looks like the circle is wobbling around something but not on the y axis itself. See video:

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=lehDAYKZ6vk&feature=youtu.be
```

Here is the peace of code I’m using in my onDraw method:

```
canvas.save();

mCamera.save();
mCamera.rotateY(rotation);

mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);

float CenterX = circle.getX();
float CenterY = circle.getY();

mMatrix.preTranslate(-CenterX, -CenterY); 

mMatrix.postTranslate(CenterX, CenterY);

mCamera.restore();
canvas.concat(mMatrix);

canvas.restore();
```

The code is almost identical to the one in the following tutorial:

```
www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html
```

In the tutorial above, the flip animation seem to work without wobbling even with the same piece of code.

Am I doing something wrong? Are there any other solutions to achieve the flip?

It seems like the perspective of the canvas will be drawn wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by setting

```
mCamera.setLocation(0,0,-100)
```

The rotation perspective will be drawn correctly now.